# Transfering SVN repo from windows to linux...?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, svn

How can I transfer these repos so that I can use them on linux? I  simply just tried to copy and paste from windows to linux but no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should dump your repository and then import it in Linux.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html.

Answer (score 4):

You would follow this basic process:

1. Dump your source (windows) repository ala:

   `C:\Path\To\Repos> svnadmin dump repoName > repoName.dmp`
2. Copy the dump file to your dest machine (linux)
3. Create a new SVN repository to house the dump file:

   `/path/to/repos> svnadmin create repoName`
4. Import the dump file:

   `svnadmin load repoName < repoName.dmp`